# Difficultieswith CoordinatorLayout implementation

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to implement a CoordinatorLayout with a GridView, how ever I'm having trouble with the xml, it doesn't look the way I want it to be. Can someone please help get it right?

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_screen_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_collapsing"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

                <!--ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/header_image_id"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/-->

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/back_to_topics_id"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:background="@color/colorBeige"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/search_panel_id"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_view_id"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:text="@string/secondary_title"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                        android:id="@+id/search_view_id"
                        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:queryHint="@string/search_view_hint"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:queryBackground="@color/colorWhite"/>

                </LinearLayout>
                 <!-- Used to hold the GridView Fragment-->
                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_layout_id"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/search_panel_id"

                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                </FrameLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>


        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As you can see in the image below, my SearchView and the text appear at the top of the screen how ever I want them to appear beneath the blue are. The white area is where I will hold my GridView items, so when I'll scroll the Grid would expend to the top with both the SearchView and the text.

[image]

Comment: AppBarLayout is supposed to be a direct child of the CoordinatorLayout. It causes issues in case its not. Please also refer to: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html

Comment: Please provide a mockup of the view you want to implement; I think you got basic things wrong concerning layouts.